# Qual a tradução correcta de "post"?

Tags: tradução-inglês

Já todos escrevemos um *"post"* ou, ao menos, lemos um *"post"*. É exemplo este *"post"* que o leitor lê.

Se quiséssemos dizer isto em português que palavra usaríamos?

(Estranha vivência esta de ler e escrever *"posts"*.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma palavra já dicionarizada é ***postagem***, que é um aportuguesamento do inglês *post*. O termo já vem no [Dicio](https://duvidas.dicio.com.br/postagem-ou-post/), [Infopédia (dicionário da Porto Editora)](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/postagem) e [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/POSTAGEM), que eu cito:

> **postagem**
> […]
> **2**. Publicação numa página da Internet (ex.: *pode agendar novas postagens no blogue*).

O termo já aparece na imprensa há uns largos anos. Exemplos do Brasil (negrito meu em todas as citações):

> O blog do Genoino, ex-presidente do PT e agora candidato federal, traz apenas **três longas postagens**, nenhuma assinada por ele, e todas referentes à sua versão da crise no PT […]
> [*Jornal do Commercio*, Rio de Janeiro, 21-8-2006](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=364568_19&pesq=%22longas%20postagens%22&pasta=ano%20200&pagfis=84306)
>
> Até o blog de Sara Kane, inativo há mais de um ano, voltou a **receber postagens**.
> [*Zero*, Florianópolis, novembro de 2008](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=895911&pesq=postagens&pasta=ano%20200&pagfis=1802)

Este exemplo de Portugal faz uma alusão às *Conversas em Família*, uns monólogos do ditador português Marcelo Caetano na televisão:

> […] Portugal é governado por um homem [primeiro-ministro Passos Coelho] adaptado aos novos tempos, capaz de fazer as ‘**Postagens em Família**’ que já Marcello Caetano poderia ter escrito caso Mark Zuckerberg e a internet tivessem nascido décadas mais cedo.
> [*Correio da Manhã*, Lisboa, 28-12-2012](https://www.cmjornal.pt/opiniao/detalhe/postagens-em-familia)

Também já está dicionarizado ***postar*** com o significado ’publicar na internet’ ([Dicio](https://duvidas.dicio.com.br/postagem-ou-post/), [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/postar), [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/postar)). *Postagem* e *postar* já antes existiam no Brasil relativamente ao envio de correspondência ou encomendas pelo correio.

Quem seja avesso a neologismos de influência estrageira, tem *publicação*, sugerido pelo Sid na outra resposta. *Postagem* tem a vantagem de ser muito mais específico, referindo-se a publicações apenas na internet.

Comment: Não acho, apesar de tudo, que se possa dizer que postagem e postar são neologismos. São usos novos ou extendidos....

Comment: @Lambie é  uma boa pergunta, não tenho aqui o dicionário de etimologia. Mas talvez seja um neologismo porque é o equivalente Inglês e Germânico de *"correio"*.

Comment: @Lambie, pois, é um neologismo semântico: 'atribuição de novas acepções a uma palavra já existente" [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/neologismos-semanticos/29269).

Comment: Jacinto,pode ir ao chat um momentinho? :)

Answer (score 2):

A tradução mais literal seria:

> publicação

**Observação:**

Em inglês, a palavra *post* é usada como verbo e substantivo. O significado do verbo é *publicar*. No [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/post) se lê:

> 1. to stick or pin a notice on a wall in order to make it publicly known
> 2. to publish something such as a message or picture on a website or using social media:

Tradução:

> 1. segurar uma notícia no mural para fazê-la conhecida publicamente
> 2. publicar algo tal como uma mensagem ou imagem num site ou ao usar uma rede social

Consequentemente, *post*, como substantivo é aquilo que foi publicado, o seja, uma publicação.

Tem outras possibilidade que são menos literais como: *conteúdo*, *mensagem*, *notícia*.

Comment: Bem observado, mas mais literal mesmo talvez seja *postagem*, para quem aceite neologismos.

Comment: publicação não é literal....como poderia ser?